# How to insert data into database from html table in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

How do I add data into a database from an HTML table?

My table is like this:

```
html += "<table>";
html += "<tr><th>" + "A" + "</th><th>" + "B" + "</th><th>" + "C" + </th></tr>";
html += "<tr><td>" + "0" + "</td><td>" + "1" + "</td><td>" + "2" + </td></tr>";
html += "</table>";
```

I'm calling the HTML from the server side.

Comment: What do you mean in "I'm calling the HTML from the server side."? Are you creating this html from server side? Please provide more details

Comment: means I wrote the above code in the .cs page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you like plain HTML, you can use a JavaScript framework like Knockout.js along with it. Knockout.js allows you to inject data into HTML using JavaScript View Models. A button click can be assigned to a JavaScript function in the View Model. The JavaScript function can do an AJAX post to call a controller action method on the server side - which will insert the data into the database.

For more information about knockout, check http://knockoutjs.com

Answer (score 0):

Use System.Text.RegularExpressions (Regex) to search pattern to replace the table tag:

replace `<tr><th>` and `<tr><td>` with blank,

replace `</th></tr>` and `</td></tr>` with `^^~~~~~~~~~~^^` indicates endline.

replace `</td><td>` with `||^^^^^^^^^||` indicates delimeters

```
string html = // your html table goes here
string[] lines = html.Split(new string[] { "^^~~~~~~~~~~^^" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
// now your html table is divided into lines, which means rows

// lines[0] = // the header
// lines[1] = // row 1
// lines[2] = // row 2
// lines[3] = // row 3
// ...
// ...

// line 1 is the header/column name
string[] columns = lines[0].Split(new string[] { "||^^^^^^^^^||" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

// columns[0] = // 1st column name
// columns[1] = // 2nd column name
// columns[2] = // 3rd column name
// ...
// ...

for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    string[] data = lines[i].Split(new string[] { "||^^^^^^^^^||" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    // data[0] = // 1st data
    // data[1] = // 2nd data
    // data[2] = // 3rd data 
    // ...  
    // ...
}
```